# Cannot be resolved or is not a field error android

Tags: android, resolve

I have checked the id exists in the R.java file still it shows error
here is R.java code

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int background=0x7f020000;
        public static final int empty=0x7f020001;
    }
```

and here i am getting error

```
empty=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.empty);//0x7f020001);
```

if i use the value directly from R.java file then it doesn't show any error

i have tried Project->Clean and fix Project properties and restarted eclipse also none of them worked somebody help me figure out this

thanks..

Comment: if i use value 0x7f020001 instead of R.drawable.empty then it dose work but problem is when R.java file will again generated then empty may be assigned a different id so it won't work at that time ..

Comment: this looks correct... what is the actual error that you're getting... I suspect you're misreading what eclipse isn't happy about?  Also, if you do use the number directly (0x7f...etc) does it actually work (as in a running application) or is it just not making eclipse complain? My guess is that even if it runs, it should crash at that point, if eclipse can't resolve the id, then there's something wrong with the data.

Comment: I have checked it again and it still shows "empty" can not be resolved or is not a field

Comment: oh, well that has nothing to do with R... you've just not declare empty correctly.  Where in your code is Bitmap empty; declared?

Comment: if i use the int value like ox7f00... then it works and runs fine on my android device but i am worried about when R.java file is recreated then it won't work...

Comment: its declared on top of the class i didn't copy whole code..

Comment: right, you should definitely not use the int value. It's just very odd that the error you're getting has to do with empty not being a valid field... that doesn't seem to have anything to do with the symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the below answer worked i.e i had to remove import android.R on the top, which eclipse automatically imported..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that maybe is a problem of the imports. Try to check the imports of your class. Sometimes Eclipse imports the R class from the android package and stops using yours.
Remove imports like `import android.R`

Comment: I refer to the `import` not to files.

Comment: ah! good catch. Yeah, you should NEVER import R. It's part of the package. you don't get anything useful from the import, unless you really are importing android.R or some other non package specific R.

Comment: i already did accepted the answer.. for that i have to only click yes on "was this answer helpful" right ? i am new to this forum so i don't know much about these stuffs please let me know i am right..

Comment: @Sandeep click the check icon (similar to nike logo), not the up arrow (sorry for my English, I don't know how to explain it :)

Comment: i did :) got to know how to accept the answers on stack overflow this is another answer from you how to accept this one :)

Answer (score 1):

R class is regenerated every time when you build your project. You mustn't save int nubmers anywhere else. You should use int values from R class directly

Answer (score 0):

In a similar case someone solved this problem by updating his sdk... Not sure if it helps.

Comment: I saw my mistake and edited my answer ;) Sorry for the inconvenience.