# "Cannot be resolved or is not a field please" why?

Tags: java, android

I have this

```
background = new Background(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.game_fon), ScreenWidth, this);
```

to insert an image to my game and this in `R.java`

```
public static final int game_fon=0x7f02000b;
```

But the `game_fon` for the background `Cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

Comment: If you have this in R.java, you should use `R.game_fon`, shouldn't you?

Comment: What is the _fon for the background called?

Comment: You need to copy your image in `res/drawable` folder of your project. Then refresh the projecr.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot be resolved or is not a field error android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035699/cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error-android)

Comment: I already have game_fon with other things in a res/drawable-nodpi folder

Comment: I also have these  ArrayList<Bitmap> animation = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode1));
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode2));
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode3));
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode4));
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode5));
  animation.add(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explode6));

Comment: Show how you are importing `R` in your activity.

Comment: the game I'm attempting to create has a lot of code, and im following an online course (I'm a beginner if you have already guessed) so I would have no idea where to look for it what would it look like AJ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the imports of your class. Sometimes Eclipse imports the R class from the android package and stops using yours. Remove imports like `import android.R`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the game_fon.png is located at "`project_root/res/drawable/game_fon.png`". And clean and re-build your project again. You can also try to restart Eclipse.